# 7zip batch to compress all folders then delete original folder

Tags: 7zip

I have a batch file which uses 7zip to zip all folders.

`for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"`

How can I delete the original folders now?

It would also be great if I could specify the size of the zip file like in the settings 'solid block style'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
for /d %%X in (*) do RMDIR "%%X" /S /Q
```

This will do what you ask. A backup is not created, so make sure that you have copied your files safely before running this command. This silently removes the folder and subfolders after zipping them.

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 7zip switch is -sdel to delete your files after archiving but the solution above works too!

`for /D %%X in ("*") do "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "D:\Downloads\%%X.7z" "%%X\" -p"PASSWORD" -mhe -v100m -sdel`

I was using the above command to compress each subfolder of the root of the script to its own archive with a password and encrypted headers, to split into 100MB chunks (%%X.7z.001, %%X.7z.002, etc) if larger than 100MB, and then to delete the original files after archival.

Comment: using sdel clearly is the better option, as it will only delete the sourcefiles, if archiving was successful. Using a seperate deletion, without validation might end up with a corrupted zip file and deleted sources. Probably not the desired outcome.